# How do I get a service to access variables in the Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller and variables declared on the $scope.

I have two arrays holding objects, one contains available groups, other contains groups the user already belongs go. The function `addUserToGroups()` makes a call to the server to take the selected groups and add the user to those groups. But then I need to update the two arrays on my Dom reflect the change. However, the service gives me an error that the `assignedGroups` array is undefined.

Controller:

```
spApp.controller('userCtrl', 
    function userCtrl($scope,userService,groupService){
        //Generate list of all users on the SiteCollection
        $scope.users = userService.getUsers();
        $scope.selectedAvailableGroups;
        $scope.selectedAssignedGroups;
            $scope.availableGroups;
            $scope.assignedGroups;

        //Boolean used to disable add/remove buttons
        $scope.selectedUser = false;


        $scope.addUserToGroup = function (){
            userService.addUserToGroup($scope.selectedUser, $scope.selectedAvailableGroups)
        };


    }
);
```

I keep passing these objects into the controller function so the service can use them and I'm sure that would work here as well, but is that really the best way to go about it? I feel like I'm just creating a bunch of global variables within that controller. Is that okay?

Service:

```
spApp.factory('userService', function(){
  var addUserToGroup = function (selectedUser, selectedAvailableGroups) {
    var addToGroupPromises = [];
    var selectedGroupsLength = selectedAvailableGroups.length

    //Add user to selected groups on server
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedGroupsLength; i++) {
      addToGroupPromises[i] = $().SPServices({
        operation: "AddUserToGroup",
        groupName: selectedAvailableGroups[i].name,
        userLoginName: selectedUser.domain
      });      
    };

    //when all users added, update dom
    $.when.apply($,addToGroupPromises).done(function (){
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedGroupsLength; i++) {
        assignedGroups.push(selectedAvailableGroups[i]);
        //groupsAvailable.pop(selectedAvailableGroups[i]);
      };
      alert(selectedUser.name + " added to: " + JSON.stringify(selectedAvailableGroups));  
    });   
  };     
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedUser" ng-click="addUserToGroup()">Add User</button>
```

I'm still very new to Angular and trying to figure out the best way to do this. Thanks.

EDIT: Also, I did it the traditional way of just passing the $scope.asignedGroups into the function and it works but the DOM doesn't update even though the ng-option should be listening for changed to the assignedGroups. I see the assignedGroups change in Batarang but the DOM doesn't.

```
<select id="entityAssigned" multiple
    ng-model="selectedAssignedGroups" 
    ng-options="g.name for g in assignedGroups | orderBy:'name'">                       
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a reason on why you couldn't create one extra function argument to accept assignedGroups in order to be used in the Service?

Comment: No not really. I'm just wondering if there's some Angular feature I'm missing which would make this simpler. With Angular everything seems so plugged in that I thought if a variable was global in a controller and the service was injected into that controller, the service should be able to read the global variables without having to pass as arguments for every service function.

Comment: If not, that's fine. I just wanted to make sure I was doing it the best way.

Comment: Yes, you could do that by passing $scope to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the codes below.

So basically, you notify angular that you want to use $scope in the your service.

```
   _app.services.YourService = function ($scope) {
         var addUserToGroup = function (selectedUser, selectedAvailableGroups) {
             var assignedGroups = $scope.assignedGroups;
         }
    }

    _app.services.YourService.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not really sure if what you've done is happening in the controller or the service.

Comment: It's happening in the service.

Comment: but you're still passing arguments inside the function addUserToGroup, I'm not sure how that improves my code. If you're injecting the $scope, why would you still need to pass in arguments to the function

Comment: @Hatjhie the way you inject `$scope` into service is not appropriate. Look at the documentation `Scopes provide separation between the model and the view, via a mechanism for watching the model for changes. They also provide an event emission/broadcast and subscription facility` So definitely it should be in `controller`.